# Pytorch Model error with shape size , but goes well with same shape size

Tags: pytorch

I am training the following model on Colab

```
model = AutoModelForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained("albert-base-v2", num_labels = 1)
```

When I run the model on my input (truncated to 512), it gives me the following error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-69-bd0200007a4a> in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 model(x)

8 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/nn/functional.py in embedding(input, weight, padding_idx, max_norm, norm_type, scale_grad_by_freq, sparse)
   2208         # remove once script supports set_grad_enabled
   2209         _no_grad_embedding_renorm_(weight, input, max_norm, norm_type)
-> 2210     return torch.embedding(weight, input, padding_idx, scale_grad_by_freq, sparse)
   2211 
   2212 

IndexError: index out of range in self
```

When I try to get the shape of input it turns out to be `torch.size([1 , 512])` (my batch size is 1)

But when I try to do the save thing with `torch.tensor([[0 for _ in range(512)]] , dtype = troch.long)`, It works well, I found that both are having the same shape as of `torch.size([1 , 512])`

I tried solving the issue with Batch Size but all in vain

Comment: I guess that's how embedding works: https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Embedding.html#embedding
It maps discrete values to a stored embedding. In other words, it only accepts discrete values, such as **long** tensors.